# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer .Unable to derive module descriptor

Tags: java, spring

[image]While running spring application i am getting error as .I am following the following tutorialhttps://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.html

I created files intially in a default package and after that created a new package and moved class to that new

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\MIDHUN\Downloads\spring-framework-5.2.3.RELEASE\libs\spring-context-indexer-5.2.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.springframework.context.index.processor.CandidateComponentsIndexer not in module
```

Answer (score -1):

i think that you should do: Spring(name-project) right click go to properties, then in java build path and try to add the jar files into classpath folder